# Use the value of a selected option of an html dropdown list as part of a src of img tag

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie in web programming and would like to use the text that is displayed in the selected option of html select as part of the source of an image tag. Below is my attempt at this.  How can I make this work?

```
<select  id="appTutor" name="TutorSelected" >
    <option value="">Click To Select</option>
    <?php  
    $serverName = "EAZYCAL-PC\EAZYCAL";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"e-APPRAISAL", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"love");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $sql="SELECT TutorID,Surname,Othernames,Department,TutorPic FROM TutorsInfo";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
    { 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['TutorID'];?>"><?php echo $row['Surname'].' '.$row['Othernames'];?>
        </option>
        <?php
    }
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
    ?>
</select>
<img id="showIMG" src="uploads/"<?php $_POST['TutorSelected']?>".jpg"/>
```

Comment: You will need JS for that!

Comment: was wondering if u could please show how....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you'll need to use JS for that.
Something along these lines should do it:

```
var select = document.getElementById("appTutor");
select.addEventListener('change',function(){
  var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("showIMG").src="uploads/" + selected + "";
});
```

Comment: Feel free to accept it if it answered your question.